# Can't SELECT on a document store added in SODA in Java Application

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, soda

I have written a little application to add documents to a collection in an Oracle Express Edition 18c database. I use the `SODA` library to do so.

```
OracleCollection col = db.admin().createCollection("MyJSONCollection");
```

Now, I want to select all entries in SQLDeveloper. The table is listed among all other tables, and i can view that it has the contents, i gave it in my program, but I got the message `undefined table` when trying to `SELECT`, and when executing the command, it won't find it. (table or view does not exist)

```
SELECT * FROM MyJSONCollection;
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * FROM "MyJSONCollection";
```

How does the table show in the navigator in SQL Developer? Is it all uppercase or is it case sensitive?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! It's shown in case-sensetive. Is there an explanation why it has to be in quotes to work in this case?

Comment: Probably because Java is case sensitive... create your collection again in ALLCAPS and then it shouldn't matter going forward as you use SQL against it